How to resolve LaTeX Error: Unicode character if Package CJK is forbbidden?
In the offical AAAI Latex package, it explicitly claims the CJK package is forbidden.
Therefore, the following error appears when the content of the paper contains such charaters.
LaTeX Error: Unicode character 》 (U+300B)

Other characters:
LaTeX Error: Unicode character 乐 (U+4E50)
not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.397 However, enjoyment~(乐
                             ) is not sufficient to describe some positive e...
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter

LaTeX Error: Unicode character 好 (U+597D)
not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.397 ...信), so an extra category, ``good''~(好
                                                  ) was added.
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter 

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 398.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 398.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <9> on input line 398.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 398.
<images/calo.pdf, id=12, 256.0748pt x 227.62204pt>
File: images/calo.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use images/calo.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: images/calo.pdf  used on input line 425.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 239.39438pt x 212.80467pt.

If I still have to use pdflatex, is there a solution for the problem?

you have changed the question since my answer. 好 (U+597D) and similar characters are basically unusable with pdftex (which has at most 128 characters per font) unless you use ctex (and a very limited font choice that has been specially created for pdftex) or use a unicode tex such as luatex. If you just want to insert a few words, typeset them in luatex or with the cjk packages for pdftex and then include them into your document with \includegraphics

Thank you! It seems changing to xelatex or luatex is the solution. The challenge is that  the compiled pdf lost the style that pdflatex presents. But this is another question.

You only show part of the error message, the full message and help text is
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character 》 (U+300B)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 》
       
? h
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter 
?

so you can declare the character to do whatever you want.
If you are (mis) using the character for math

\documentclass{article}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{300B}{\gg}
\begin{document}

$a 》b$

\end{document}

If you are using it as Latin punctuation:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{300A}{\guillemotleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{300B}{\guillemotright}
  
\begin{document}

 aaaa 《bbb》 ccc

\end{document}

Or any other approximation that you want (you may prefer >> or \rangle\rangle or ...)

Thanks! However, how about other common characters? I updated my question for more general cases.

@VisualJoyce "common" depends on what you are doing. If you are really typing Chinese then basically you are doomed, you should use a Unicode system. However there are a few CJK punctuation characters that are (or were) commonly used with latin script, mostly as an approximation to math symbols, before the math symbols were added to Unicode.
